# What Are ArcGIS Client and ArcGIS Portal?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, client

I can understand what does it mean when people are talking about ArcGIS Server but not understanding what is the ArcGIS Client and what is the ArcGIS Portal for?

Can you please let me know what are these two concepts?

Comment: [What is Portal for ArcGIS](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/what-is-portal-for-arcgis-.htm). Client means any application that is retrieving/sending data with the Server. Could be a web app, ArcMap, etc.

Comment: Recommend giving this video a watch. http://video.esri.com/watch/3600/ismael-chivite-on-arcgis-for-server-and-arcgis-online

Answer (score 2):

A client is any application that consumes one or more services, so a client may be service that consumes another service. Similarly most (web) portals are clients.  Literally they (portals) provide a window onto data provided by others (usually) through services.

Generally speaking when people talk about clients, such as ArcGIS client, they mean a bit of software that sits on a PC (desktop GIS), it can consume online services (such as WMS, WFS, WCS, JavaScript driven APIs...), but also use local databases and files.